# Placing label within the packed bubble - highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a packed bubble chart and here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytvcjzx1/

Here is the code:

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Series, 'afterDrawDataLabels', function(e) {
    const series = this;
    const chart = series.chart;

    if (!series.parentNode.plotX || chart.options.chart.type !== 'packedbubble') {
      return;
    }

    if (!series.customLabel) {
      series.customLabel = series.chart.renderer.label(
          series.name, null, null, 'rect'
        )
        .attr({
          align: 'center',
          fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
          zIndex: 3
        })
        .css({
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap', // To prevent text wrapping
          padding: '5px', // Add some padding around the label text
          borderRadius: '5px' // Add rounded corners to the background
        })
        .add();
    }

    series.customLabel.attr({
      x: series.parentNode.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
      y: series.parentNode.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble',
    height: '100%'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Carbon emissions around the world (2014)',
    align: 'left'
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}m CO<sub>2</sub>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      minSize: '20%',
      maxSize: '100%',
      zMin: 0,
      zMax: 1000,
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
        splitSeries: true,
        seriesInteraction: false,
        dragBetweenSeries: true,
        parentNodeLimit: true
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}',
        filter: {
          property: 'y',
          operator: '>',
          value: 250
        },
        style: {
          color: 'black',
          textOutline: 'none',
          fontWeight: 'normal'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Europe',
    data: [{
        name: 'Germany',
        value: 767.1
      }, {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Belgium',
        value: 97.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Czech Republic',
        value: 111.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Netherlands',
        value: 158.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Spain',
        value: 241.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Ukraine',
        value: 249.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Poland',
        value: 298.1
      },
      {
        name: 'France',
        value: 323.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Romania',
        value: 78.3
      },
      {
        name: 'United Kingdom',
        value: 415.4
      }, {
        name: 'Turkey',
        value: 353.2
      }, {
        name: 'Italy',
        value: 337.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Greece',
        value: 71.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Austria',
        value: 69.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Belarus',
        value: 67.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Serbia',
        value: 59.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Finland',
        value: 54.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Bulgaria',
        value: 51.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Portugal',
        value: 48.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Norway',
        value: 44.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Sweden',
        value: 44.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Hungary',
        value: 43.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Switzerland',
        value: 40.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Denmark',
        value: 40
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovakia',
        value: 34.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Ireland',
        value: 34.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Estonia',
        value: 19.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovenia',
        value: 16.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Lithuania',
        value: 12.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Luxembourg',
        value: 10.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Macedonia',
        value: 9.5
      },
      {
        name: 'Moldova',
        value: 7.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Latvia',
        value: 7.5
      },
      {
        name: 'Cyprus',
        value: 7.2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Long word 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222',
    data: [{
        name: 'Senegal',
        value: 8.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Cameroon',
        value: 9.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Zimbabwe',
        value: 13.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Ghana',
        value: 14.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Kenya',
        value: 14.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Sudan',
        value: 17.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Tunisia',
        value: 24.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Angola',
        value: 25
      },
      {
        name: 'Libya',
        value: 50.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Ivory Coast',
        value: 7.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Morocco',
        value: 60.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Ethiopia',
        value: 8.9
      },
      {
        name: 'United Republic of Tanzania',
        value: 9.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Nigeria',
        value: 93.9
      },
      {
        name: 'South Africa',
        value: 392.7
      }, {
        name: 'Egypt',
        value: 225.1
      }, {
        name: 'Algeria',
        value: 141.5
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
});
```

You notice the series name `Long word 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222` is well outside the bubble. Can we enable text overflow and make sure all series name are displayed only within the bubble (like adding the ellipsis `...`), for example the text can be `Long word 1234432222...` so that user can hover and find its full version via the tooltip? Or is it possible via css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the custom label appear inside the bubble you could try this modification to your rendered label:

```
series.customLabel = series.chart.renderer.label(
      series.name, null, null, 'rect'
    )
    .attr({
      align: 'center',
      fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
      zIndex: 3
    })
    .css({
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap', // To prevent text wrapping
      padding: '5px', // Add some padding around the label text
      borderRadius: '5px', // Add rounded corners to the background
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      width: series.parentNode.graphic.width
    })
    .add();
```

Which adds `textOverflow: 'ellipsis', width: series.parentNode.graphic.width`.

See [this initial JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/teqzmphy/), or [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/kpbL62ex/) that has some padding and handles window resizing.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add some padding to both left and right of the text so that it looks good? I think the padding doesn't work which already part of our css.

Comment: @Ant's if you do `width: series.parentNode.graphic.width - 10` then it should center, making it sort of a 5px padding on each side. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I did the exact same thing. One last question, can the background fill be made as rounded corners?

Comment: @Ant's I'm not sure. When inspecting the background it seems to be drawn as a `path`, which I find odd. When a `path` is used I would say no. The [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label) seem to mention `path` or `rect`. If it were a `rect` you could probably utilize `rx` somehow. I'm not sure of the top of my head why a `path` was used here...

Comment: Yeah, I made it to `rect`. https://jsfiddle.net/3yc24qxn/. Where should I use the `rx` attribute, to make it rounded corners?

Comment: @Ant's take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/cgkjt6ep/, which adds `series.customLabel.element.childNodes[0].setAttribute("rx", "10")`. I'll just note I'm not sure how safe `childNodes[0]` is, so maybe make it safer.

Comment: For completeness, it would probably be best to place the width outside the `if` that handles the initial rendering, so that the width is adjusted dynamically with window resizing. E.g.: https://jsfiddle.net/kpbL62ex/